# Sort elements HTML with javascript [without framework]

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

I can't find a clear solution to sort elements displayed on screen.

I'm expecting that after clicking button NAME, elements displayed on the screen will be sorted alphabetically. I'm beginner in programming so I don't know how to ask question in google to find solution how to do it.

I found something like sort function but it doesn't work. It works when I displayed list in console log but on page nothing happening.

```js
let closebtns = document.querySelectorAll("span");
//add animal button form
const addMovieModal = document.getElementById('add-modal');
const startAddMovieButton = document.querySelector('section button');
const backdrop = document.getElementById('backdrop');
const cancelAdd = addMovieModal.querySelector('.btn--passive');
const addButton = addMovieModal.querySelector('#btn--success');
const userInput = addMovieModal.querySelectorAll('input');

const clearInputs = () => {
  for (const usrInput of userInput) {
    usrInput.value = "";
  }
}

let listOfAnimals = [{
    name: "Meowsalot",
    age: 10,
    type: "cat",
    favFoods: ["tuna", "catnip", "celery"]
  },

  {
    name: "Barksalot",
    age: 7,
    type: "cat",
    favFoods: []
  },
  {
    name: "Barksalot",
    age: 10,
    type: "dog",
    favFoods: ["tuna", "catnip", "celery"]
  }
];
const name = "NAME: ";
const age = "AGE: ";
const typ = "TYPE: ";
const favFood = "FOOD: "
document.getElementById('li').innerHTML = name + listOfAnimals[0].name + "</br>" + age + listOfAnimals[0].age + "</br>" +
  typ + listOfAnimals[0].type + "</br>" + favFood + listOfAnimals[0].favFoods + "</br>";
document.getElementById('li1').innerHTML = name + listOfAnimals[1].name + "</br>" + age + listOfAnimals[1].age + "</br>" +
  typ + listOfAnimals[1].type + "</br>" + favFood + listOfAnimals[1].favFoods + "</br>"
document.getElementById('li2').innerHTML = name + listOfAnimals[2].name + "</br>" + age + listOfAnimals[2].age + "</br>" +
  typ + listOfAnimals[2].type + "</br>" + favFood + listOfAnimals[2].favFoods + "</br>"

const addNewAnimal = () => {
  const nameAnimal = userInput[0].value;
  const type = userInput[2].value;
  const ageAnimal = userInput[3].value;
  const image = userInput[1].value;
  if (nameAnimal.trim() === "" ||
    type.trim() === "" ||
    image.trim() === "" ||
    ageAnimal.trim() === ""
  ) {
    alert("Please enter a valid value ");
    return;
  }
  const newAnimal = {
    name: nameAnimal,
    url: image,
    type: type,
    age: ageAnimal,
  };
  listOfAnimals.push(newAnimal);
  console.log(newAnimal);
  toggleMovieModal();
  renderLiElement(newAnimal.name, newAnimal.type, newAnimal.age, newAnimal.url);
  clearInputs();
};
addButton.addEventListener('click', addNewAnimal);
const renderLiElement = (type, name, age, imageURL) => {
  const newLiElement = document.createElement('li');
  newLiElement.innerHTML = `<li class="animalElement">
            <img alt="${imageURL}" src="${imageURL}">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <ul class="ulOfLi">
                <li>Name : ${name}</li>
                <li>Age :  ${age}</li>
                <li>Type : ${type}</li>
                <li>Food </li>
            </ul>
            </li>`;
  newLiElement.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', closeFunction);
  const listRoot = document.getElementById('ulList');
  listRoot.append(newLiElement);
  newLiElement.style.border = 'none';
}

const toggleBackdrop = () => {
  backdrop.classList.toggle('visible');
};

const toggleMovieModal = () => {
  addMovieModal.classList.toggle('visible');
  toggleBackdrop();
};

const cancel = () => {
  toggleMovieModal();
  clearInputs();
};

startAddMovieButton.addEventListener('click', toggleMovieModal);
backdrop.addEventListener('click', toggleMovieModal);
cancelAdd.addEventListener('click', cancel);


//close li element
const closeFunction = function() {
  this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
};
for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
  closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", closeFunction);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="Zadanie1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="Zadanie1.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="titles">
      <h4>Sort</h4>
      <h4>Filter</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="controlPanel" id="controlPanel">
      <button id="sort-age">AGE</button>
      <button class="sort-name" id="sort-name">NAME</button>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Types" id="input-number" />
      <label for="input-number"></label>
    </div>
    <ul class="UL" id="ulList">
      <li class="animalElement">
        <img alt="cat-2" src="dog-1.jpg">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <ul class="ulOfLi" id="li2">
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="animalElement">
        <img alt="cat-1" src="cat-2.jpg">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <ul class="ulOfLi" id="li1">
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="animalElement">
        <img alt="dog-1" src="cat-1.jpg">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p class="ulOfLi" id="li">
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="modal card" id="add-modal">
      <div class="modal__content">
        <label for="name"></label>
        <input type="text" name='name' id="name" placeholder="NAME" />
        <label for="imageURL"></label>
        <input type="text" name="imageURL" id="imageURL" placeholder="url" />
        <label for="type"></label>
        <input type="text" name="type" id="type" placeholder="TYPE" />
        <label for="age"></label>
        <input placeholder="AGE" type="number" step="1" max="20" min="1" name="age" id="age" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal__actions">
        <button class="btn btn--passive">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn--success" id="btn--success">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section>
      <button class="add">&times;</button>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Most often, it's easier and faster to sort data of the elements instead of literally swapping elements around. When having a short list only, you can [read the elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) into an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array, and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) the elements from the array to the parent element.

Comment: Start by moving your JS file to AFTER the HTML (before the `</body>`  it will work here in the snippet I made because the snippet adds a load event for the JS